# Find records from one table which don't exist in another & users mapped from third table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL & trying my hands-on.

Looking for an efficient way to get users (*) which are present in user table but not present in temp table

Have three tables:

```
Temp:

member_no | name

User:

endUserId | name 

Login:

member_no | endUserId
```

I tried this but not working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM User LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Temp
      ON User.endUserId = (SELECT TOP 1 e.endUserId
                           FROM User e JOIN
                                LOGIN l
                                ON e.endUserId = l.endUserId 
                           WHERE l.username = Temp.member_no
                          )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want users that are not in temp, then `not exists` or `not in` come to mind:

```
select u.*
from user u
where not exists (select 1
                  from temp t join
                       login l
                       on t.memberno = l.memberno
                  where l.endUserId = u.endUserId
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like breeze! Let me add explanation what's happening here, so my understanding is verified. by inner select statement we're joining temp & login table data on memberno & filtering that data where endUserId similar to user table. Then picking up all the data from user table which doesn't match from the inner select statement!